# How to fix a Symfony site broken after migration? (failed to open stream: No such file or directory)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I moved old site based symfony to new server, and when I enter I have error:

> Warning: require_once(//../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line
>   4
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '//../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php'
>   (include_path='.:/:/usr/local/php56/lib/pear') in /index.php on line 4

I suppose this has to do with the newer version of php on the server (5.6). How can I fix it?

Comment: Or maybe your paths are wrong

Comment: Paths are the same as before. Only host changed.

Comment: I'm not sure how symfony works and what happens when you first set up the environment but `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line 4` means it cannot locate the `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` call found on line 4, Maybe open up index.php and see if you can fix it.

Comment: Could be an autoloading issue too I guess... did you try to clean your cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved .htaccess file to main folder and set the redirect to /web catalog.
I set the domain to main catalog.
These solutions have proven to be effective and work.

Thanks all for help and guides.

Answer (score 1):

Well, most likely that file either isn't present where `index.php` tries to find it or access is forbidden.

First, find the localtion of your `index.php` file. Then, go to `//../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` (not sure why there's 2 `/` in the path, but go to the parent folder, then to the `config` subfolder and find `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`). Finally, check the permissions for `ProjectConfiguration.class.php`.

If you fail to find the `../config/` folder or there's no `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` in it you should fix that (if you find `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` in another folder, you can try to change the path in `index.php`); if reading/executing is not permitted for `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`, you can try to change that (set 777 first, restrict closer to the initial state if it helps).

Still, I don't quite understand what is `//../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php`: if the line is

```
require_once(//../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php)
```

that should be a syntax error (stuff after `//` is a single-line comment), so please add the line 4 of `index.php` to your post if my suggestions don't help.